# Vim in OSX: How to paste text from open window into a open file in vim?

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

In linux, I used <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste anything in the system clipboard into the terminal. In Mac, there isn't an insert key - so, I'm left wondering how to do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard Mac paste shortcut, Command-v, should paste the contents of the clipboard into vim, running in a terminal window, assuming vim is in insert mode. I just pasted the previous sentence into vim on my Mac, by that method.  If you are new to Macs, and you have an Apple keyboard, the Command keys have an apple and a strange symbol resembling an octothorpe, with a loop at each corner.  On my 3rd party keyboard, they are labeled with a diamond-shaped symbol.

Answer (score 5):

This works with Macvim. The copied text is placed in the `+` register then in the macvim buffer hit `"+p` and the text will be pasted into the buffer. I find this quicker than using command-v,comand-c.

If you're using console vim then it is placed in the `.` register. Hit `".p` to paste the text from the clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> is used to paste highlighted text, not to paste text copied in the buffer that was copied using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

In macOS this functionality of pasting highlighted text can be done with <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

I hope this helps any users that are coming from Ubuntu.